# Manage mysql fetch array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a mysql table that has data in it that I need to use in a more basic format.

There is ID number, Date, oil, gas and electric values.

I can do a mysql_fetch_array which brings back all the values I need but I need to view them in a format for use with a javascript chart. They need to be in the format:

```
$data = array(array("6/22/2009",425.32),array("6/8/2009",424.84),array("5/26/2009",417.23),array("5/11/2009",390));
```

As you can see I need the date and the oil values. Then I need to create another array with the date and electric values and finally the data and the gas values.

I'm not sure how to get the data from the mysql_fetch_array and add it to the array as shown above. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can just append it via the `[]` syntax:

```
$data = array('oil' => array(), 'gas' => array(), 'electric' => array());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data['oil'][$row['date']] = $row['oil'];
}
```

This assumes that the dates selected are unique as well.

---

By the way, you should avoid using `mysql_*` functions in new code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a 'numerical array':

```
    $result = mysql_query(" SELECT date, oil FROM energyprices");
    $i = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
         $oil[$i] = array($row[0], $row[1]);
         $i++;
    }
```

Correct me if I haven't understood your question and I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$finalArray=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    $data=array();
    $data[] = $row['date'];
    $data[] = $row['oil'];
    $finalArray[]=$data;
}
print_r($finalArray); //This will print your values in required fromat.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I have amended my code to read this:

```
$oil = array('oil' => array());
$result=mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM energyprices");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$oil[$row['pDate']]['oil'] = $row['oil'];
}
```

When I print_r the data it looks like this:

```
Array ( [oil] => Array ( ) [2004-01-01] => Array ( [oil] => 29.73 ) [2004-01-02] => Array ( [oil] => 29.73 ));
```

The format I need it in is:

```
$oil = array(
array("6/22/2009",425.32),
array("6/8/2009",424.84),
array("5/26/2009",417.23));
```

Thank you!